# Error when running the resnet50.py for my own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, resnet

I'm running the 'resnet50.py' in the following Github repository.
https://github.com/anujshah1003/Transfer-Learning-in-keras---custom-data

But when running the code I'm getting the error,

```
- ETA: 5:38:49
  4718592/102853048 [>.............................] - ETA: 5:40:22
  4726784/102853048 [>.............................] - ETA: 5:41:52
  4734976/102853048 [>.............................] - ETA: 5:43:24
  4743168/102853048 [>.............................] - ETA: 5:44:10Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET\resnet_50\dbs2017\resnet_3_original.py", line 290, in <module>
    model = ResNet50(require_flatten=True, weights='imagenet')
  File "C:\CT_SCAN_IMAGE_SET\resnet_50\dbs2017\resnet_3_original.py", line 259, in ResNet50
    md5_hash='a7b3fe01876f51b566af0dea6bc144eb')
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 221, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\urllib\request.py", line 217, in urlretrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\http\client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\http\client.py", line 488, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\ssl.py", line 791, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\ssl.py", line 575, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Does any one know why such error generates time to time? Where is the issue can is generating? This is to complete my research at uni.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message Keras is trying to download some component from remote server but the connection is reset, which is possibly caused by your ISP if your Internet connection is OK. So you need to solve the connection problem first.